# cerrar aplicaciones desde el SDK de android

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna librería o método que me permita ver los procesos que están corriendo en el dispositivo y cerrar alguno, por ejemplo la app de YouTube.

Utilizó eclipse y el SDK de android.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes ver en el mismo IDE, cuando tienes tu dispositivo conectado, desde el DDMS en la sección Devices:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi puedes ver los procesos ejecutandose en el dispositivo, puedes seleccionar y detenerlos.

En el caso de Android Studio, puedes ver los procesos por medio del Android Device Monitor.